# Azure AD Single Sign On

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2b

My company has developed a web-based application for internal and external use. The application is developed by angular + asp.net WebApi and authorised by OAuth. Users have to use the username and password given by us to login. The application works well. Recently, clients made a new request to login our system through Azure AD SSO. They want us to integrate their Azure AD.

Requirements:

1. On login page, there should be a new option for users to login our system by connecting to their Azure AD.
2. Alternatively, if their employees are connected to their system and then visit to our website, they will be automatically logged in our website without entering username and password.

I have no knownledge about Azure AD SSO and still get confused even I did some search on google. Can someone give me some advice or hints?

Answer (score 0):

Using Msal with Angular you can implement the Azure AD SSO login. There are multiple code samples and microsoft documents available to achieve your requirement.

Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular#how-the-sample-app-works) and [code Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi).

In the Angular sample there is a function as mentioned below which [verifies](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi/blob/master/TodoListSPA/src/app/app.component.ts#L49) the user credentials if the user is already logged in or not.

```
checkoutAccount() {
    this.loggedIn = !!this.authService.getAccount();
  }
```